# A question about enums defined inside a class in java

Tags: java, enums

This code is taken from a SCJP practice test:

```
 3. public class Bridge { 
 4.   public enum Suits { 
 5.     CLUBS(20), DIAMONDS(20), HEARTS(30), SPADES(30), 
 6.     NOTRUMP(40) { public int getValue(int bid) { 
                        return ((bid-1)*30)+40; } }; 
 7.     Suits(int points) {  this.points = points;  } 
 8.     private int points; 
 9.     public int getValue(int bid) { return points * bid; } 
10.   } 
11.   public static void main(String[] args) { 
12.     System.out.println(Suits.NOTRUMP.getBidValue(3)); 
13.     System.out.println(Suits.SPADES + " " + Suits.SPADES.points); 
14.     System.out.println(Suits.values()); 
15.   } 
16. }
```

On line 8 `points` is declared as private, and on line 13 it's being accessed, so from what I can see my answer would be that compilation fails. But the answer in the book says otherwise. Am I missing something here or is it a typo in the book?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

All code inside single outer class can access anything in that outer class whatever access level is.

Answer (score 5):

To expand on what stepancheg said:

From the [Java Language Specification section 6.6.1 "Determining Accessibility"](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/names.html#6.6.1):

> if the member or constructor is
>   declared private, then access is
>   permitted if and only if it occurs
>   within the body of the top level class
>   that encloses the declaration of the
>   member or constructor.

Essentially, `private` doesn't mean private to this class, it means private to the top-level class.

Answer (score 3):

First check out line 12

```
  System.out.println(Suits.NOTRUMP.getBidValue(3));
```

getBidValue is undefined

Comment: @Vasil: on line 6 it says "getValue" not "getBidValue"

Comment: sorry, so there is a typo after all. +1 for noticing that.

Comment: This code appears in this book: http://amazon.co.uk/dp/0071591060

But in my book copy line 12 is:

    System.out.println(Suits.NOTRUMP.getValue(3));

I don't find any typo in this code.

Comment: @aovila I have only an electronic version of the book and I copied and pasted, maybe it's corrected in print

Comment: @Vasil my print and electronic versions have the same line I wrote before, maybe your copy is out of date. Be careful, maybe your copy has more typos like this!

Answer (score 0):

Similarly, an inner class can access to private members of its outer class.